# How to set a cookie using JSF when Internet Explorer is running in "Enhanced protected mode"

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf, cookies, setcookie

We use the following code to set a cookie:

```
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) context.getExternalContext().getResponse();
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(name, value);
    cookie.setMaxAge(lifetimeInSeconds);
    cookie.setPath("/");
    response.addCookie(cookie);
```

However, we see cookies are not being set in Internet Explorer when "Enhanced protected mode" is enabled. How can we eventually DO set a cookie? Do we have to use another API? We are using JSF 1.2 (Mojorra 2.0.3 - b5)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem on Jetty and IE 11. Could you provide more information like the server you are running, IE version. Do you mix http and https? Have you checked this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/10/internet-explorer-beware-cookie-sharing-in-cross-zone-scenarios.aspx

Comment: We are running on a JBoss 6.1.0-Final application server. Our application is accessed through HTTP